# Query results as comma-delimited string without using PIVOT?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, pivot

i want to create a query from multiple records as one record , but i don't want to use Pivot, FYI , i have > 260 Records , it is impossible if i Write Manual PIVOT,
is there any Simple solutions?

here's the table Example :

```
ID   Element_Name  Value
1    Parmitha      100
2    Anggun        200
3    Chandra       300
4    BagusofTerror 400
5    Laras         500
6    Jessica       600
7    Aisyah        700
......
200 Sonya          20000
```

and i want the result is like this :

```
paramitha , anggun, chandra , bagusofterror, Laras , Jessica , Aisyah, ..... , Sonya
100 , 200, 300, 400,500,600,700,....,20000
```

Comment: So...you want to pivot the data without using the pivot operator?

Comment: no i dont want a pivot operator,are there any solutions?

Comment: There are also ways you could still use the pivot operator without having to write it all out manually, but it generally requires dynamic queries. http://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2007/09/14/pivots-with-dynamic-columns-in-sql-server-2005/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In reference to http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/12/21/sql-server-comma-separated-values-csv-from-table-column-part-2/ you could use the following SQL query

I havent run this, so I'm not 100% sure it'll work

```
SELECT STUFF(
(SELECT ',' + s.ElementName
FROM tableName s
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') 

UNION ALL

SELECT STUFF(
(SELECT ',' + s.Value
FROM tableName s
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
```

Answer (score 0):

We used to call this a cross-tab query. Not sure if it still is...

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN id=1 THEN value ELSE 0 END) AS parmitha,
   SUM(CASE WHEN id=2 THEN value ELSE 0 END) AS anggun,
   SUM(CASE WHEN id=3 THEN value ELSE 0 END) AS chandra,

   ...etc...

   SUM(value) AS total
FROM My_Table
WHERE ...etc...
```

I don't know c#, but I'm sure you can get it to loop over the column to prepare the SUM().

Answer (score 0):

How about this that I tried on the sample dataset you provided.

```
declare @intFlag int
Declare @AnsString nvarchar(2000)

SET @intFlag=1
SET @AnsString=''

While (@intFlag<=200)
Begin
     Select @AnsString=@AnsString
                       +CONVERT(Varchar(20),(SELECT [Element_Name]
                                              FROM TABLE where RowID=@intFlag))
               +', '
SET @intFlag=@intFlag+1
if @intFlag=199
break;
END
Print @AnsString
--Select @AnsSTring
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want this data in separate columns, then you can use dynamic SQL to `PIVOT` the data in SQL Server 2005+.  Your code would be similar to this:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(element_name) 
                    from yourtable 
                    group by element_name, id
                    order by id
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query 
    = 'select '+@cols+'
       from
       (
         select Element_name, Value
         from yourtable
       ) p
       pivot
       (
          max(value)
          for Element_name in('+@cols+')
       ) piv'

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ab310/3). This gives the result:

```
| PARMITHA | ANGGUN | CHANDRA | BAGUSOFTERROR | LARAS | JESSICA | AISYAH | SONYA |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|      100 |    200 |     300 |           400 |   500 |     600 |    700 | 20000 |
```